# Does the deployment rollback to the last deployed build if the post-deployment gate check fails?

Tags: azure-devops

We are using the Azure DevOps pipeline for our extensions deployment.
I want to take advantage of the post-deployment gate to stop the deployment and rollback to the last deployed build in case we receive some IcM incidents after deployment.

Does the deployment auto rollback to the last deployed build if the post-deployment gate check fails?

Comment: Hi @arpitgagneja, is the explanation in my answer helpful to you? if you have any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thanks @BrightRan-MSFT for providing a detailed answer. I have accepted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my tests, when the Post-deployment gates fail, the pipeline will not rollback to the last successful deployment.

According to the introduction in the docs about "[**Release approvals and gates overview**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops)", the Post-deployment approvals and Post-deployment gates are executed after the deployment process has completed. They generally are used to determine if the release is promoted to the next stages.

[image]